# Is this cat male or female?

Tags: cats, gender-differentiation

I think it's a male because of the distance between the anus and the opening below it, just want outside confirmation.

[image]

Comment: It's such a subtle difference that I can't tell at first glance. That's why I asked.

Comment: it is a neutered male cat,the neutering makes it harder to see if it had been intact there had been testicles so a lot easier to see.

Comment: Thank you Trond!